# How to create anchor link to user name coming from relation relationship

Tags: laravel, voyager

[Amit should be linkable to users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs2Na.png)
How to make a user name to linkable from Voyager admin, Basically i want to display history of payment and relation of users.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the user attribute in the User model.

```
public function getUserAttribute($value){
  return "<b>$value</a>" // here you can modify the attribute, so you can make a link to the payment.
}
```

[Source](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/customization/bread-accessors)

I hope this will help you ;)

Comment: In the user model.